# What kind of encoding is this and what does it translate to? }(]&[([%!"=))%%!")"

Tags: encoding, decode

```
}(]&[([%!"=))%%!")"}"{"={}]+&"{*="!&"&&]!+}"{])"=]#)!!)]"][}{*/[(#{*%*[#=&)}""]}
{]]%/)(="{![{)=&%{}&+{#)%==#"(*})+%%)(+{)(%*{}!&"=&[#]&*)%+/})+/)!!#{%)+)()+!=[(
)=}([={[!{/)+)&/"]!/=!+*%(&/)#")!*[#(#(="][*=+(*&/!)!()+#)#}[%]*"#")*(#]{&*%%)}#
%*({"+)/#&""=&=/})={)}")"%}]%+&*#={)//=+(}/"!{%!!{=%/}}!}](}*"/]&&%=}*[*(&["={%{
}#&){#%[%[)%)+%}/&#%(/=((][}}["]=!&))!/[]#&"=]=[*+#*{])="]"/[#]]*!"}![)%})(&"/*#
...
```

I've never seen an encoding like this before. I've tried all sorts of online automatic decoders to no avail, and googling "code with curly braces and parenthesis" isn't doing me any good. Above are the first four lines out of exactly 1000 lines.

Here's a pastebin link since it wouldn't fit into the 30000 body character limit. https://pastebin.com/4LfEvd4b

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: @Artyer It's part of a "challenge" posted by a Swedish web hosting company. This is the last step in the challenge, with the former challenges being stuff like decoding base 64 found in a .tar file inside of a .zip file etc... So what they're saying on this step is "look in the HTML", where I found this as a comment.

Comment: Well, there are some characters that stand out: 2 `v`s, 1 `s`, 2 `e`s and 2 `r`s, spelling `vserver`. Maybe check the HTTP `Server` header? The other interesting thing is it has 15 characters (That are not in `vserver`), which is almost a multiple of 2 so it could be base 16 (Like mapping to `0123456789abcdef` and reading as a hex string)

Comment: Also, it's exactly 80000 characters long, in 1000 lines 80 chars per line.

Comment: Heeeey! You did it! The answer was vserver. I was running regex to extract any a-z characters but obviously I'm not up to speed on my regex then. Thank you very much for your help, here's the link to the challenge if you're interested (in Swedish though...) https://portal.beebyte.se/c/

Comment: @Artyer How do I mark you as the accepted answer? Never posted here before.